# Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 < |z| < 1\}$ with essential singularity at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-sequences, analytic-functions

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $D^{*} = \{z \in  \mathbb{C}: 0 < |z| < 1\}$ with essential singularity at 0.

Show that for each $w \in \mathbb{C}$, exists a sequence $\{z_n\} \in D^{*}$
such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n) = w$.

I know that we can cover almost the whole complex plane as we approach to the essential singularity and Casoratti Weierstrass says that the closure of the image of f under the annulus is $\mathbb{C}$. The problem is how we construct that sequence!

I was trying to prove by contradiction, that is: for any sequence in $D^{*}$ exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(z_n) - w| \geq \epsilon$. I did not find anything usefull.

Comment: I suppose that you meant that $\lim_n z_n=w$.

Comment: If $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-w}$ is analytic then $f$ is meromorphic and analytic.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand something, your proposition is false.

Consider $f(z) = e^{1/z}$, it has an essential singularity at $z=0$, but there is no $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)=0$.

---

Perhaps you are asked to prove

> Show that for each $w\in\mathbb{C}$, exists a sequence $\{z_n\}\in D^\ast$ such that $f(z_n)\to w$.

In this case, this is a simple corollary of Weierstrass-Casorati.

---

Perhaps, alternatively, you are asked to prove

> Show that for each $w\in\mathbb{C}$, with a single exceptional $w$, there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}\in D^\ast$ such that $f(z_n)= w$.

In this case, this is equivalent to great Picard theorem.

Comment: I fixed the question. This is a PHD Qualifying problem, and I can not say that it's just a corollary of Casorati, which I know. I have to prove the existence of these sequence and that's my problem.

Comment: Or maybe by contradiction. I know the proof of Casoratti but we never talk about analytic continuation.

Comment: @RichardClare Look at $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-w}$

Comment: @reuns I have done that. then we write $f(z) = \frac{1}{g(z)} + w$ and if the limit $z\to 0$ is 0 then it has a removable singularity, if $\infty$ it has a pole, and contraditcs the assumption.

Comment: @RichardClare Is it analytic ?..